# If explorer is already running

Tags: vb.net

I have a system that backs up data to a network with certain parameters in place such as:

*'If x process is running, do not run the backup'*

Because it's connected to a network, users will constantly be on it. The problem I have is that I don't want the data to get moved onto the network if it's in use, plus, the data is unable to move across if someone is using file explorer on the same computer as the program is on.

I would use *'If explorer is running, do not run the backup'* but explorer is linked to windows and is always running

```
If program.Count > 0 Or program2.Count > 0 Then
   Try
      Msgbox("Process Running")
   Catch ex As Exception
   End Try
Else
   'backup data
End If
```

Is there a way to try get the program to transfer files, but if fails because the file directory is already open, then do x?

Comment: Explorer is always running. Even if no file explorer window is visible, if someone is logged in the explorer.exe process is always running as part of the desktop.

Comment: _ the data is unable to move across if someone is using file explorer_ - what a weird condition. Out of curiosity, how did you get that limitation?

Answer (score -2):

Try this. It should generate an error if you can't lock the file.

```
Public Function IsFileLocked(file As FileInfo) As Boolean
    Dim stream = DirectCast(Nothing, FileStream)
    Try
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
    Catch generatedExceptionName As IOException
                'handle the exception your way
        Return True
    Finally
        If stream IsNot Nothing Then
            stream.Close()
        End If
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Why didn't you post an answer instead of commenting other's answer and down vote them ?

Comment: Why do you assume I'm the one who downvoted? As I said... this is headed in the right direction. I also stand by the complaint in the comment (thus no upvote), but after a couple hours with no upvoted answers a question will re-appear on the front page. It could have been anyone.